# Spring integration unable to find outbound socket error

Tags: spring, sockets, spring-integration

After processing the request received from a specific server response.
But "Unable to find Outbound socket" error occurs.

Error message is...

```
2016-06-15 10:06:41.784 ERROR 5916 --- [task-scheduler-6] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket
at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(TcpSendingMessageHandler.java:113)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:101)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
....
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Debug log is...

```
2016-06-15 10:06:41.773 DEBUG 5916 --- [task-scheduler-6] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'flowForConvertingPlainJsonToBytes.channel#2', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[201], headers={json__ContentTypeId__=class java.lang.String, json__TypeId__=class java.util.HashMap, ip_tcp_remotePort=62114, ip_connectionId=192.168.3.96:62114:5001:9f5bfc60-9e72-44e8-813d-2884b2e12ae1, ip_address=192.168.3.96, id=6dccdee4-7edd-d9bc-c0ac-aa58ebd8a6c7, json__KeyTypeId__=class java.lang.String, contentType=application/json, ip_hostname=192.168.3.96, timestamp=1465952801773}]
2016-06-15 10:06:41.775 DEBUG 5916 --- [task-scheduler-6] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : plainHandler received message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[201], headers={json__ContentTypeId__=class java.lang.String, json__TypeId__=class java.util.HashMap, ip_tcp_remotePort=62114, ip_connectionId=192.168.3.96:62114:5001:9f5bfc60-9e72-44e8-813d-2884b2e12ae1, ip_address=192.168.3.96, id=6dccdee4-7edd-d9bc-c0ac-aa58ebd8a6c7, json__KeyTypeId__=class java.lang.String, contentType=application/json, ip_hostname=192.168.3.96, timestamp=1465952801773}]
2016-06-15 10:06:41.778 ERROR 5916 --- [task-scheduler-6] o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : Unable to find outbound socket for GenericMessage [payload=byte[201], headers={json__ContentTypeId__=class java.lang.String, json__TypeId__=class java.util.HashMap, ip_tcp_remotePort=62114, ip_connectionId=192.168.3.96:62114:5001:9f5bfc60-9e72-44e8-813d-2884b2e12ae1, ip_address=192.168.3.96, id=6dccdee4-7edd-d9bc-c0ac-aa58ebd8a6c7, json__KeyTypeId__=class java.lang.String, contentType=application/json, ip_hostname=192.168.3.96, timestamp=1465952801773}]
2016-06-15 10:06:41.780 DEBUG 5916 --- [task-scheduler-6] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket, headers={id=152129a7-062a-409b-2f2d-7c5843ba8296, timestamp=1465952801780}]
2016-06-15 10:06:41.782 DEBUG 5916 --- [task-scheduler-6] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : (inner bean)#8c49d03 received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Unable to find outbound socket, headers={id=152129a7-062a-409b-2f2d-7c5843ba8296, timestamp=1465952801780}]
```

`ip_connectionId` is exists. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Either the corresponding socket has been closed or you're sending to an outbound adapter that's associated with the wrong connection factory.

DEBUG logging should help you.

Also, when asking questions like this, you should always include your configuration.

Comment: We glad to see that you are good now, but really would be better to share the solution with all other people to help